# Rails Partial with variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, renderpartial

**UsersController**

```
def index
    @users = User.all.paginate(page: params[:page])   
end
```

**users/index.html.erb**

```
  <% @users.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |users| %>
    <% users.each do |user| %>
      <% unless current_user == user %>
        <div id="follow">
          ????????????
        </div>
      <% end %> 
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
  <%= will_paginate @users %>
```

**I want to turn the following into a partial, 'users/_follow_form'**

```
<% if current_user.following?(user) %>
  <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: user.id),
    html: { method: :delete }, remote: true) do |f| %>
        <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, user.id %></div>
      <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**What code do I need to use to render it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="follow">
   <%= render partial: "users/follow_form", locals: {passUser: user} %>
</div>
```

This will pass your `<% users.each do |user| %>` **user** to the partial assigned as `passUser`. You can get this `passUser` variable in the `users/_follow_form` partial like:

```
<% if current_user.following?(passUser) %>
```

Check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-render.htm) for more.